# Constructor call is giving error-Inheritance

Tags: java

In a child class `GreenSlime` Im given a constructor with only three parameters (I cannot add any other instance variables). But the code keeps giving error about this line:`super(loc,map,log);` which I understand that the constructor should have the same amount of parameters. But my specs say that via the parent constructor, sets all fields. `fullcharge` must always be `4`, and the starting value for `charge` is `0`. I do know that I'm passing only 3 parameters instead of 5, but that's the instructions of my project say so. What am I doing wrong and what's the best approach/solution?

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
public class GreenSlime extends Threat  {

    public GreenSlime(Coord loc, Map map, PrintStream log)
    {
        super(loc,map,log);
        super.fullCharge = 4;
        super.charge = 0;
    }

}
import java.io.PrintStream;



public abstract class Threat extends Thing {

    protected int charge;
    protected final int fullCharge;

    public Threat(Coord c, String repr, int fullCharge, Map map, PrintStream log)
    {
        super(c,repr,map,log);
        this.fullCharge = fullCharge;
        charge = 0;
    }

    public abstract void spawn(Coord c);

    @Override
    public void doAction()
    {

        while(charge != fullCharge)
        {
            System.out.println("\"+repr()"+"@"+"getLoc()\" speading");

            if(this.canPassThrough())
            {
                spawn(getPrevLoc().step(Direction.N));
                spawn(getPrevLoc().step(Direction.S));
                spawn(getPrevLoc().step(Direction.E));
                spawn(getPrevLoc().step(Direction.W));
            }
            charge++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can only set a final field exactly once.

Comment: Also, the Threat constructor takes 5 arguments, and you're trying to only pass it 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
public GreenSlime(Coord loc, Map map, PrintStream log)
{
    super(loc,"",4,map,log);
}
```

I've supplied an empty string "" for repr, but you may need null or some other value.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the **Threat constructor** has a signature that accepts 5 arguments, but where as you're trying to pass only 3 arguments to it.

Comment: I understand that. My specs are restricted to such constructors.

Comment: @joshua Then you need to use varargs which accepts any number of arguments..!! You can check about varargs at http://www.j2eekart.com/2014/12/varargs-in-java.html